# Migrate from NGUI to Unity UI

Tags: unity, gui, ngui

I used NGUI 2 and NGUI 3 for our UI. Now want to upgrade to Unity 4.6 and migrate all NGUI to Unity UI. Is there any tools? What's the best practice?

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge there are no tools, they're completely separate systems. You could reuse the assets and any function calls through the UI etc so it wouldn't be a total redo but you'll have to remake it.